# Pointer to statically defined two-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c99, multidimensional-array

Code (compiled using `gcc -std=c99`) ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int mytype[8][8];

int main(void)
{
    mytype CB;
    for (int r=0; r<8; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<8; c++) {
            CB[r][c] = 5;
        }
    }

    mytype *CB2 = &CB;

    for (int r=0; r<8; r++) {
        for (int c=0; c<8; c++) {
            printf("%d ",*CB2[r][c]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

prints on `stdout` wrong data (only data for the first row are right) which are supposd to be all `5`. I found out, that pointers for other array items are kind of shifted in memory but I do not see why.

The purpose is, I hope, obvious: to set contents of array `CB` in first loop and then print it out in the second loop. This is model only - the pointer thing is there because I need it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's worth reading up on operator precedence before you are trying to use operators, this question fits the "too localized" category very well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) means that you need to change

```
printf("%d ",*CB2[r][c]);
```

to

```
printf("%d ",(*CB2)[r][c]);
```

The array subscript operator `[]` has higher precedence than the pointer dereference operator `*` so your code was being evaluated as `*(CB2[r][c])`